# Creating Entites of a Table

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to create an entity object without mapping all the columns of the table. Suppose I have a table USER_PROFILE having columns UP_ID, UP_NAME, UP_TYPE. while creating the entity is it possible to map only UP_ID and UP_NAME?

Comment: Sure, you want to make the non-mapped properties transient.   If you're using annotations, there's a @Transient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all variable are mapped with database table column so if you want to exception for a column the use @transient annotaion.

@transient keyword is used to denote that a field is not to be serialized and not persist in database.